# Slow upsert query with low cost in explain

Tags: postgresql

I have a slow query (500 ms):

```
INSERT INTO "addresses" ("address") VALUES (...) ON CONFLICT ("address") DO UPDATE SET "address"='',"is_x"=false;
```

That is trying to upsert into a table with 1M records. Server is large and optimized.

I am trying to diagnose that when I run `EXPLAIN` I get:

```
Insert on addresses  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=0.063..0.063 rows=0 loops=1)
  Conflict Resolution: UPDATE
  Conflict Arbiter Indexes: addresses_pkey
  Tuples Inserted: 0
  Conflicting Tuples: 1
  Buffers: shared hit=8
  ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=203) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=66
Planning Time: 0.192 ms
Execution Time: 0.082 ms
```

With subsequent runs at:

```
Insert on addresses  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=0.046..0.046 rows=0 loops=1)
  Conflict Resolution: UPDATE
  Conflict Arbiter Indexes: addresses_pkey
  Tuples Inserted: 0
  Conflicting Tuples: 1
  Buffers: shared hit=7
  ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=203) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.025 ms
Execution Time: 0.058 ms
```

What could be the issues here? Any tips much appreciated.

Comment: The duration is no more then 0.3 milliseconds, so this does not show the problem. Try to catch a slow execution. Or do you have a high network latency to the database server?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - Thank you for help.  You are right, it must just be network latency or something with the client connections. Was just seeing a warning in logs and thought it was something I could see by analyzing the query.  Thank you very much for your help.